# Datetime equal or greater than today in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

What's the best way to do following:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created >= today;
```

Note: created is a datetime field.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created >= CURDATE();
```

But I think you mean `created < today`

You can compare datetime with date, for example: `SELECT NOW() < CURDATE()` gives `0`, `SELECT NOW() = CURDATE()` gives `1`.

Comment: `CURDATE()` return only date not time

Comment: @n00b how do you have users who are created in the future..? interesting =) I was using this to see if a post had expired yet.

Answer (score 94):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE  DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but with DATETIME types, the CURDATE() solution doesn't work.  This does.

Comment: plus this takes a lot of time as there is overhead of converting DATETIME to date via the DATE() function and then comparing with the where condition.

Comment: Do not use functions on columns, it makes the query to ignore index, causing slow queries. Check my answer for alternative approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365426/4311336

Comment: "equal or greater than today" - how does your answer resolve that? How could it return any row where `myDate` is in the future?

Answer (score 47):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created >= NOW();
```

if the column is datetime type.

Comment: i mean today not now :D i need today like 2011-03-03 not 2011-03-03 14:02:02

Comment: @n00b: it will returns rows greater than today don't worry if the time is included

Comment: lets say it's 2011-02-02 14:02:02 - users that have been created at 10:02:02 wouldn't be returned in your version even though they were created "today" :)

Comment: @n00b: Lol ya, no users would ever be returned, if only we could stop time.

Answer (score 30):

Answer marked is misleading. The question stated is `DateTime`, but stated what was needed was just `CURDATE()`.

The **shortest and correct answer** to this is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 18):

If 'created' is datetime type

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

CURDATE() means also '2013-05-09 00:00:00'

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually needed DATE_SUB (used in the same way), but this put me on the right path.

Comment: This will not return data where date contains 0s in time, i.e '2013-05-09 00:00:00' will be missed out

Comment: "equal or greater than today" - how does your answer resolve that? How could it return any row where `myDate` is in the future?

Answer (score 15):

If the column have index and a function is applied on the column then index doesn't work and full table scan occurs, causing really slow query.

Bad Query; This would ignore index on the column date_time

```
select * from users
where Date(date_time) > '2010-10-10'
```

To utilize index on column **created** of type **datetime** comparing with today/current date, the following method can be used.

Solution for OP:

```
select * from users
where created > CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59')
```

Sample to get data for today:

```
select * from users
where 
    created >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND
    created <= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59')
```

Or use BETWEEN for short

```
select * from users 
where created BETWEEN 
      CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59')
```

**Tip:**
If you have to do a lot of calculation or queries on dates as well as time, then it's very useful to save date and time in separate columns. (Divide & Conquer)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE created >= now()
```

Comment: This won't return the records before this moment from today.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me.

```
declare @Today date

Set @Today=getdate() --date will equal today    

Select *

FROM table_name
WHERE created <= @Today
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT( SUBSTRING(json_date, 11, 4 ) ,  '-', SUBSTRING( json_date, 7, 2 ) ,  '-', SUBSTRING(json_date, 3, 2 ) ) >= NOW();
```

**json_date ["05/11/2011"]**

Comment: This is a very raw solution

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Where does `json_date` come from?

Answer (score -6):

you can return all rows and than use php datediff function inside an if statement, although that will put extra load on the server.

```
if(dateDiff(date("Y/m/d"), $row['date']) <=0 ){    
}else{    
echo " info here";    
}
```

Comment: this is very slow compared to the database select

Comment: This won't work if the OP won't use PHP after all