# Mysql daily downloads counter

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am loosing it a bit and cant think of this sql correctly

I have

tables:
userid , counter , date  and

I need to check how many files has user downloaded in last 24h , starting sql

```
SELECT SUM(counter) FROM download_log WHERE userid = 258 AND date = DATE(NOW())
```

but it is returning null , and I downloaded min 40 files ,
date format in date table is

```
2012-05-05 01:59:55
```

I also tried ,   `date = NOW()`

same thing 
what am i missing ?

thank you!

Comment: similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be:

```
SELECT SUM(counter) FROM download_log where userid = 258 and date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```

You have to get all rows within the last 24 hours.

Comment: i think you on th right way but im getting  error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: I fixed a typo, function should be DATE_SUB, not DATE_SUM.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(counter) FROM download_log WHERE userid = 258 AND date = CURDATE()
```

That should work.

Comment: currdate works in this combo only  AND DATE(  `date` ) = CURDATE( ) , thnx for this

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you are storing date and time in column named `date` , so it should work :

```
SELECT SUM(counter) FROM download_log WHERE userid = 258 AND 
DATE(`date`)= DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: this works perfect but I am wondering , this should be 24h right?

Comment: That doesn't actually return #files downloaded in last 24 hours ; it returns #files downloaded today (it may or may not be what you want). If you need exactly 24 hours from now, it should be `WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND date < NOW()`. Also, "date" should be in backticks.