# How to retrieve data from a mySQL database based on current month using the [DATE] function?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Okay so am using this structure in my SQL database:

```
id  |  title  |   date_start   |   date_end|  time_start   |   time_end   |   location   |
```

I am wanting to sort data from that table, but only the upcoming dates or dates that are currently occurring.

I've used the following query in php:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events3 ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Then after the query I fetched the results, then echoed them as so:

http://pastebin.com/5wS7npsr

That would display the only two dates in the database as:

```
ID:   2
Title:   New Years Eve
Date Start:   2012-12-31 - 2012-12-31
Time Frame:   12:00:00 - 12:00:00
Location:   Earth
Description:   The last day of 2012.


ID:   1
Title:   Christmas Day
Date Start:   2012-12-25 - 2012-12-25
Time Frame:   12:00:00 - 12:00:00
Location:   Earth
Description:   Merry Christmas!!
```

But I want it to expire after the date has occurred and only show the next upcoming ones.

Comment: Sounds like you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql

Comment: But how to do it from today on? Which query?

Comment: What field types are they? DATE, string etc?

Comment: The function that date_start and date_stop use is DATE and time_start and time_end use TIME

Comment: `SELECT * FROM events3 WHERE date_start >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT 5;`

Comment: Thank you. But now thats returning them starting with for example new years before christmas

Comment: Right, that's because you have a desc query modifier, try removing the desc from the query and xmas will appear before nye.

Comment: But woudn't that display more than 5 results?

Comment: You can keep the limit, just remove the `DESC`. So you want this: `SELECT * FROM events3 WHERE date_start >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 5;`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, there is a similar post here: [Datetime equal or greater than today in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql)

Ultimately, after some back and forth, the resulting query for your specific implementation:

```
SELECT * FROM events3 WHERE date_start >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 5;
```