# Only display event if it's a date after today?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP to insert events from a SQL database into a table in HTML, and I'm trying to make it only display future events (or events taking place the same day). The events are stored in the SQL database with "start" column having dates like `2014-12-25 00:00:00`.

I was previously using this code to display all the dates:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['title'] . "</td><td>" . date("l, F d Y", strtotime($row['start'])) . " </td></tr>";
  }
```

And it worked fine. When I tried to compare the dates to yesterday (to ensure that events today would display) the HTML page was completely blank. Here's the code I'm using:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if(strtotime("yesterday") < strtotime($row['start'])) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['title'] . "</td><td>" . date("l, F d Y", strtotime($row['start'])) . "</td></tr>";
  }
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with this, but for some reason it works. I did some debugging and

`strtotime($row['start'])` outputs 1419483600

`strtotime ("yesterday")` outputs 1419742800

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You said that one output is 1419483600 and the other is 1419742800, is there actually a record that has `strtotime($row['start'])` value higher than 1419742800? ;)

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing `)` in your `if` statement.

Comment: showdev is right, have you got startup error reporting enabled on your server? If not, syntax errors will "blank" the page.

Comment: The closing `)` was due to copy/pasting error.

Comment: As a debugging exercise, what happens if you remove the if statement? Specifically what dates show up? In addition paste the `strtotime()` value. Also, what timezone are your dates stored in the database? The unix time is UTC/GMT I think?

Comment: You should filter your data in your queries, look at this question to filter your data instead of filtering after all the data is pulled. It will simplify your code, increase efficiency and lower  execution time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql

Comment: Huh, maybe I was missing something. I just retyped the entire while  loops and now it seems to work. Thanks everyone for their help, though!

Comment: better way to filter your data by date in your SQL query, just use something like `select * from events where startdate > sysdate`