# Compare DATETIME column with today

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare datetime column in mysql db with today.

Actually I want to add an if string, so if the return result is greater than a given number, it does something, and if it's smaller it does something else.

Can you help me out here?

Comment: Show us what you got so far and we can start a conversation

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime equal or greater than today in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

fetch **DateTime** from the database and compare with PHP default function **now()**.
for make condition use **if condition**.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, for the late reply, but I managed to figure it out myself... Here is the result:

```
$date1 = date_create($row["column"]);
                $date2 = date_create(date("Y-m-d");
                $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
                if ($interval->format('%R%a days') < 350) { echo '<td class="column-table">';
                echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); 
                echo '</td>';
        }
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.